# Python 3 input function: Arrow keys doesn't work

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I have this small code from my project:

```
while True:
    x = input(">>> ")
```

Everything works fine, but when I want to use the arrow keys, to see the last commands I typed in, it inserts ***^[[A*** (Code for Arrow-up, for example)

I'm using Raspbian and LXTerminal (I also tried GnomeTerminal).
On Windows everything works fine. Using the arrow keys in the normal terminal or in the Python shell also works fine.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> Using the arrow keys in the normal terminal or in the Python shell also works fine.

This is because someone wrote some code in these programs to perform a specific action when you press the up arrow. Your program doesn't cycle through history when you press the up arrow because you haven't written the logic to do this. The `input()` function doesn't give you this functionality for free. You have to write it yourself or find a library that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code you have to add a special function with your keyboard.
https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

This would be the right kind of module for this task